# Editing in accidental "answers" by the querent into their question

Tags: discussion

This is regarding https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/67397/revisions. The querent had posted an answer that was really a comment indicating further details to their question which disqualified an actual proposed answer. I flagged the "answer" and then copied the content of it into the question since I figured that there was otherwise a risk of useful information being lost. That was reverted recently. Did I overstep again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My bad.  I compared the users, and misread the question asker's user name, so I thought they were different names.  I've undone my revert.

Comment: No worries. I was confused at first too, thinking that the person who'd submitted an answer had created an account and submitted a new answer to comment on their prior one.